# I could not log out completely from Stack Overflow in order to login another account?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, login, logout

I successfully logout from Stack Overflow. But my friend try to login his account it is logged on my account only. How to avoid this?

Comment: I think this is probably your second account. Please merge this with old account.

Comment: @hims056 Not like that me and my friend are sharing same PC.

Comment: But you are only less then 2 hours old in Stack Overflow. So I suspect this is your second account (by mistake). :)

Comment: If you tell people to merge accounts, please tell them HOW to merge accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close and open the browser after you logout. If doesn't work please clear your browser cookies.