# How can you login to stack overflow with different username?

Tags: support, login

I'm on a new computer and I tried one of my email addresses that I thought was for my main account.

It's not and my Mac's remembering my Stack Overflow user.

How for the love of all that is holy can you simply change your user to your OTHER Stack Overflow account?

Is this in the login UI and I'm missing it? This shouldn't be so hard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need multiple accounts?  It is not forbidden persay, but there is rarely a useful reason to have multiple accounts for most users

Comment: But this post might be helpful - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156323/i-could-not-log-out-completely-from-stack-overflow-in-order-to-login-another-acc

Comment: I have no idea.  Since I don't log in manually all the time, I'll try one email address or the other on different computers.  It turns out I made two accounts.  One has a 1 reputation and one has 400+.  I made a mistake.  Now I'm trying to log in from the account I use all the time and I'm wasting a lot of time trying to find out how.

Comment: Log out. Then, log in using the openid related to the other account.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but open ID says there is no account by that name.  The account is a stack overflow account, not an open ID one. Trying to clear my StackOverflow cookie now.

Comment: Just deleted cookies, quit and relaunched FireFox. Still auto logging in to the wrong account.

Comment: Merge the accounts.  That will solve the problem.

Comment: Great.  Where can I do this?

Comment: I can't find the current instructions. but I think you click on "My Logins" from your user profile and add your other account.  That should merge your accounts.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @AsheeshR I think that is outdated.  I believe there is a automatic way to do it yourself now.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that and it automatically logged me back in again.  This is quite a PITA.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AsheeshR or maybe not.  I thought it was changed to prevent you from having to email the community team at one point

Comment: I realized why I had two accounts.  I wanted to use one browser and one account to handle one Stack Overflow site and one for another.  I simply wanted a unique login for each topic and didn't want to confuse the two.

Comment: Why would you create different accounts to follow two separate topics? Just search for the relevant tag(s) on SO, from one account.